# Installing openvpn on nao robot

Tags: linux

I'm trying to install openvpn on nao robot wich is running openNao os(OpenNAO is a GNU/Linux distribution based on Gentoo).

Problem is `emerge` is not working (command not found). `apt-get` is not working either(command not found).

I tried to download openvpn from their [webpage](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html) and installing it manually. So I downloaded the file, copied it onto a robot, used tar to unzip it. And tried to use `./configure` to install it. But there is no gcc compilator there so `./configure` did not work.

So I downloaded openNao os for virtual machine(has compilator, emerge is working etc.). I run vm in virtual box and downloaded openvpn there,unziped it and used:

```
./configure --prefix=/tmp/openvpn
mkdir /tmp/openvpn
make
make install
```

I then copied the contents of slib, include etc. to the same named directories on real nao robot.

But than trying to run openvpn client.ovpn I have the same error: command not found.

I have tried everything as normal user as well as sudo.

Answer (score 0):

The last approach with in-VM compilation seems to be reasonable and almost correct. However I would advise to do the following :

- `./configure --prefix=/usr/local`
  I do not really understand you decided to set prefix in /tmp directory. It points to the drectory you want to install the app, I would advise to stick to the default (not setting it, or picking `/usr/local` as your prefix)
- `make`
  All fine here.
- now, transfer the directory with the compiled binaries to your robot. Before transfer it would be nice to create single archive. Use `tar cfz /tmp/openvpn_compiled.tgz`
- at your robot system extract the archive's content : `tar xzf openvpn_compiled.tgz`
- enter the directory you extracted and issue : `make install`

Now it should be operating perfectly fine.